# Vim: recognize character sequences as part of "whole word"

Tags: vim

This has been bugging me for a while: I'm writing code that uses verilog-auto which means I'm editing in a verilog file with perl snippets injected into comment sections. One very useful thing that I like to do in Vim is to search for the whole word under the cursor with `*` and `#`. However, with perl syntax that contains variable names such as `${w}` and `$w`, these shortcuts don't work.

I don't want to add `$`, `{` and `}` to my "keywords" list as there are many instances where I don't want these to count as part of a whole word. For instance, in verilog concatenation: `{sig1,sig2[1:0]}`, I wouldn't want `{sig1` to be searched for as a whole word.

Is there a way to get "whole word" to recognize sequences via a regex or something? So only `${[a-z]+}` or `$[a-z]+` gets recognized as "keywords".

Either that or a separate keyboard shortcut that can let me search for the pattern under the cursor.

Comment: Well, it's not the ideal solution, but you could visually select what you're searching for and do `:vnoremap * y/\<"\><cr>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a really ugly hack, but it works:

```
nnoremap * viW:s/\%V\$*{*\a*}*/\=setreg('a', submatch(0))/n<cr>/<C-r>a<cr>n
nnoremap # viW:s/\%V\$*{*\a*}*/\=setreg('a', submatch(0))/n<cr>/<C-r>a<cr>N
```

The only downside is that this will overwrite your last visual selection, so if you use `gv` a lot, this isn't the best solution. It also overwrites the `a` register, although you could pick a different one if you want.

Comment: Hmmm, that one selects the whole line though for things like:
`.out(sig${w}Word[1:0]),`
Ideally, in this case, I'd like it to select and search for 'sig${w}Word'